# Refining description of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, logging, nsdictionary

I want to see objects classes of my dictionary in console log. As for standard `NSObject` subclasses, I override `-(NSString*) description` in category:

```
-(NSString*) description
{
    NSMutableString* desc = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"<%@ 0x%08x>\nobjects count: %ld", [self class], (uint)self, [self count]];
    for (id key in [self allKeys])
        [desc appendFormat: @"\n%@ = %@ (%@)", key, [self objectForKey: key], [[self objectForKey: key] class]];
    return desc;
}
```

It works, but only for top-level `NSDictionary` object (if the object has dictionaries in children they are logged bypassing `description` method). So `NSDictionary` prints its children objects in some way without calling `description` on them...

Is there an approach to log these children dictionaries through my `description` method?

PS: In practical situation I want to find an object in dictionary that can't be saved to `plist`. Maybe there is another solution, I would be thankful for that too.

Comment: You could try calling `description` explicitly?

Comment: Do you mean to iterate through the dictionary? Iterating would be difficult because the dictionary is complex enough, and one of its children is incorrect.

Comment: I think @trojanfoe suggests to replace `[self objectForKey: key]` with  `[[self objectForKey: key] description]`

Comment: If we pass `obj` for `%@` while formatting string, `description` is called implicitly.

Comment: I have added an answer with what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a recursive `description` method:

```
// Private Methods
@interface MyClass ()
- (NSString *)_description:(id)object;
@end
```

...

```
- (NSString *)_description:(id)object
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)object;
        NSMutableString *desc = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"<%@ %p>\nobjects count: %ld", [dict class], dict, [dict count]];
        for (id key in [dict allKeys])
        {
            [desc appendFormat: @"\n%@ = %@ (%@)", key, [self _description:[objectForKey: key]], [[self objectForKey: key] class]];
            return desc;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return [(NSObject *)object description];
    }
}

- (NSString *)description
{
    return [self _description:self];
}
```

You'll probably want to pass an incrementing indentation counter so you can format the child objects better, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks. This has a sense for custom case. I have mixed dictionaries inside arrays, so I should tune up this method...

Comment: @brigadir Actually `_description:` would be better implemented as a class method of some utility class and therefore usable from multiple objects, not just this one.